# Algebraic intuition for writing $i$ in polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers

If I'm using $re^{i\theta}$ take $e^{2 \pi i}$ and use $r = i$ gives me $i$.

Using $i = \cos{\pi/2} + i\sin{\pi/2}$ with a radius of 1 translating it back to polar form as $e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i}$, I also get $i$

I'm confused on how the two are algebraically the same, and which one is used more frequently.

Comment: r is a real number which is the modulus of the complex number how can r be $i$.

Comment: $r$ is usually assumed to be a nonnegative real number.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious! Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $r e^i\theta$ form, both $r$ and $\theta$ are assumed to be real numbers, not complex; $r$ is typically taken to be nonnegative as well.

But it IS true that as you've noticed, 
$$
i = e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i},
$$
which looks a little odd. I don't think I've ever seen the thing on the right used to express "$i$", but I'm sure it's appeared.

And, of course, it's also true that 
$$
i = i e^{2\pi i}
$$
but probably no one every writes that, either. It's like writing $17$ by writing $17 + 8 - 8$. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint

In the polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$ $r$ **must** be a real number (usually positive).

Comment: What you write is correct, but perhaps misleading, because $\mathbf i e^{2\pi \mathbf i}$ is a perfectly legitimate expression in the complex number field. It just happens to have the general "shape" of the so-called "polar form", while not matching the conditions. I think that it's worth noting that it's an OK thing to write ... just not polar form.

Comment: I agree: $ie^{i2\pi}$ is perfectly legitimate, but it's not a polar form.